# How do I write my (foreign) name in Japanese?

Tags: names

So I've been quite curious for some time as to what my name could be in Japanese.
Here's my full name: Chaima Ben Hassen (it's Tunisian).
Although i did some research and found that it was written this way in katakana, im still not sure if that's correct: チャイマ·ベン·ハッセン
Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance ☺️

Answer (score 3):

You want the katakana version of your name to represent how it is pronounced.

- If you pronounce your name *SHY-ma*, it would be written as シャイマ.
- If you pronounce your name *CHAI-ma*, it would be written as チャイマ.
- If you pronounce your name *cha-EE-ma*, it would be written as チャイーマ.

(Here, "ch" is pronounced like in "cheese", and "ai" sounds like "eye".)

I'm pretty certain the last part, ベン・ハッセン, is correct either way. Just attach whichever version of your first name is correct to get your full name, e.g. シャイマ・ベン・ハッセン.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :D

Comment: @Chaimabeha no worries! Out of interest, how do you pronounce your name?

Comment: Oh it's "Chai (or eye) - ma" :D